# How can I add a responsive bar to my portfolio page to resize the browser nicely

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, portfolio

I was wondering whether anyone knows of a prebuilt solution to resize the browser nicely on a portfolio page.  Ideally I want icons above my page (fixed) to represent ipad, iphone, desktop and when you click on them it resizes.

I saw this really good example on Template Monster
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45308.html

At the top in the bar.  It also shows the device surrounding the page which is a nice touch.

I would have thought there was a pre-built solution out there, but if not I'll build my own.  Does anyone know of a nice pre-built one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading your site within an iframe on the page and then using some JS hooked up to the click events of the said icons to change the size of the iframe? Similar to the http://iphonetester.com/

Comment: This could also be similar to what you need https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Design-Testing

Comment: That is kind of what I need to do, but I was wondering if there was a nice pre-built solution.  I'm hoping for a more substantial answer but we'll see.